How to Successfully Unsubscribe from Google Calendar Webhook
I am having a great experience with my Google Calendar integration, and so far, everything is working as expected. When a user connects their calendar, I subscribe to the webhook using the endpoint:
/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/watch

The subscription works perfectly, and my webhook receives notifications correctly. However, I am facing an issue when I try to unsubscribe from the webhook. I follow the recommendation in the documentation and use the method:
/v3/channels/stop

Although this method returns success, I continue to receive events as if the unsubscription didn't occur. I have confirmed that the channelId and resourceId are correct, reviewed the permissions requested from the user, and everything seems to be in order. Additionally, I checked the logs and the API responses from the stop method, and everything appears to be functioning correctly.
What might be happening? I am wondering if I missed something important or if there is a detail I overlooked. I've tested all the alternatives mentioned in the documentation and forums, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Does UUID ('id') in stop request match with the one returned during subscription?

post the code/request you used to stop notifications.
